# Nokogiri: copy node and add new parent to copy?

Tags: ruby, copy, nokogiri, parent

Any idea how to copy a node and then give it a new parent, with the goal of writing the copy to a new file?

I've noticed that when I reassign one node to be another's parent, nothing happens.  For example,

```
doc.xpath("/child").each do|child|

  # copy node to new structure. also tried dup()
  copyofchild = child

  # create new node to become newdoc's parent
  mom = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new('mom', copyofchild)

  copyofchild.parent = mom

  puts copyofchild  # lists <child>...</child>, not <mom><child>...</child></mom>

  # write newdoc to file...   
end
```

The one example on the docs page shows something analogous working, although they're reassigning one item in a structure to be the parent of another item in the same structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = '<xml><bar>text</bar></xml>'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

bar = doc.at('bar')
bar.parent.children = '<foo>' + bar.to_xml + '</foo>'
puts doc.to_xml
```

Which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml>
  <foo>
    <bar>text</bar>
  </foo>
</xml>
```

Alternately, you can do it like:

```
bar = doc.at('bar')
bar.replace('<foo>' + bar.to_xml + '</foo>')
```

Part of the problem in your code is your XPath accessor:

```
"/child"
```

doesn't do what you think. It only finds a top-level `<child>` node, not one farther in the tree. In my example XML it'd be the equivalent to the `<xml>` node. Perhaps you want `//child` which finds `<child>` nodes throughout the document.

Personally, I prefer CSS accessors over XPath. Both are nicely supported by Nokogiri, and both make some things easier than the other, so it's good to be familiar with both.

Comment: Thanks.  The string concatenation works.  The XPath I used was actually correct;  I was looking for all "child" nodes off the original parent.  (Obviously, the node names have been changed to illustrate the point.)

Comment: If you don't want to use serialization/deserialization, you can do: `bar.replace('<foo/>').first << bar`